# Linux kernel utility function that takes symbol string as input and return its address

Tags: linux, kernel

Is there an API in linux that can give me the address of the symbol passed in as string input?
For example, in the below function, I need the same output as shown in the print of &begin1.

the reason that I need this programatically is that I have labels like begin1, begin2, begin3 etc...in my program and I have to run a loop to get their addresses.

extern void *begin1;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buf1[30], buf2[30];

```
int i= 1;
asm volatile ("nop;\n"
       "nop;\n"
       "begin1:\n"
       "nop;\n"
       "nop;\n"
       "nop;\n"
       "nop;\n"
       "nop;\n"
       "nop;\n"
       "lbl1:\n"
       "nop;\n"
       "nop;\n"
       );


printf("&begin1 = %p\n", &begin1); //NEED THIS OUTPUT

sprintf(buf1, "begin%d",i);
sprintf(buf2,"lbl%d",i);

//Q: Can we pass buf1 as input to a kernel function that can give me the same output as above? 

return 0;
```

}

Comment: It is application code, not kernel code. So mentioning the kernel in the question and as a tag is wrong.

Comment: **Why do you ask?** What is the motivation of your question?

Answer (score 1):

A program with a `main` function cannot be kernel code. It is application code started by [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) -e.g. by your shell-
(and applications interact with the kernel thru [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall) listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)...)

<sup>On Linux, your kernel code is often a kernel module for some custom driver.</sup>

You could use [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and `dlsym` (and you need the symbols to be global, so use `.global` directive in assembler). You then want to link your program with `-rdynamic` flag (and the `-ldl` library), call `dlopen` with a NULL path, and use `dlsym` on that program handle.

Notice that `dlopen` is not a syscall (it uses `open` and `mmap` ...)

BTW, you might be interested by GCC [label as values](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html) extension.